# How to import a json file with _id (string) as _id (objectId) in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array which has multiple objects and objects have _id (string) already set. While I import the file, i want all _id (string) to get imported into _id (objectId).

I have tried manually using "$oid" but it is not a dynamic solution to my problem.

my import statement

```
mongoimport --db delivera --collection restaurants --drop --file list.json --jsonArray
```

my example object

```
{
"_id":"5a6900fff467be65019a9001",
"date":"2018-01-24T21:56:15.353Z",
"title":"Italian pasta",
"restaurant": "coffee bean",
"__v":0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try importing to a temporary collection & inserting it from there,

in your case,

```
mongoimport --db myApp --collection tempCollection --drop --file list.json --jsonArray
```

From mongo shell

```
db.tempCollection.find().forEach(function (doc) {
    doc._id = doc._id + ''
    db.restaurants.insert(doc)
});
```

Note: The answer was seen somewhere before, wasn't able to find in stackoverflow, may be some forums.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a node.js script for doing import

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/delivera"; //host and db
var file = require('./myfile.json');

MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
    var dbo = db.db("delivera"); //db
    file.map(elem => {
        elem._id = ObjectID(elem._id)
        dbo.collection("restaurants").insertOne(elem, function(err, res) { //collection
            if (err) throw err;
        });
    })
    console.log("done")
    db.close();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [ObjectId()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) method available in mongoDB shell which returns a new ObjectId value

Your object will look like this

```
{
"_id": Object("5a6900fff467be65019a9001"),
"date":"2018-01-24T21:56:15.353Z",
"title":"Italian pasta",
"restaurant": "coffee bean",
"__v":0
}
```

Comment: This will not be `json` format. Coverting it to valid `js` would work.